# How to transform data from paginated API to pandas DataFrame in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I need to get some data from a REST API for the creation of a web-map. I want to have a look first at the data and that's why I try to transform json into pandas dataframe. When it is just one page from API my code (below) works well, but when I'm looping through all pages and storing results in a list it gives me an error. What I'm doing wrong? Is there another way?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
import pandas as pd 
import folium
import json 

api_url = "https://pmap.minregion.gov.ua/index.php?r=api/document&access-token=[my token]&limit=500"

response = requests.get(api_url).json()
api_dataset = response

#looping through and putting data to the list api_dataset
for page in range (1, 62):
    response = requests.get(api_url + f"&page={page}").json()
    api_dataset.extend(response)

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 

pmap_data = json_normalize(api_dataset) #transformation to dataframe
```

And here I receive the error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'". But again, with one page from API this method worsk perfectly.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-eb5bf90e478d> in <module>
----> 1 pmap_data = json_normalize(api_dataset)
      2 pmap_data.shape

E:\Programming\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\normalize.py in json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep)
    208             # TODO: handle record value which are lists, at least error
    209             #       reasonably
--> 210             data = nested_to_record(data, sep=sep)
    211         return DataFrame(data)
    212     elif not isinstance(record_path, list):

E:\Programming\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\normalize.py in nested_to_record(ds, prefix, sep, level)
     71 
     72         new_d = copy.deepcopy(d)
---> 73         for k, v in d.items():
     74             # each key gets renamed with prefix
     75             if not isinstance(k, compat.string_types):

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: what does the rest of the stacktrace look like?

Comment: I added the Traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. There were some strings that got into the list of responses from API along with dicts. Checked and deleted them with the following code:

```
all(isinstance(x, dict) for x in api_dataset) #check if there only dicts

for x in api_dataset:
    if type(x) == str: 
         api_dataset.remove(x)

len(api_dataset)
```